# EF Core 3.1 Removing parent entity with child relations + save changes + reuse same child id in new parent = concurrent exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Situation before doing anything :

```
class Parent: { int ParentId, Child Children: [] }
class Child: { int ChildId, int ParentId }
db.Parents: [{ ParentId: 1, Children:[ ChildId: 10, ParentId: 1] })
db.Children: [{ ChildId: 10, ParentId: 1 })
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```cs
...
using var db = new DB();
var entity = await db.Parents.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.ParentId == 1);
db.WorkdayResults.Remove(entity);
await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // After saving: db.Parents and db.Children will be empty
var entry = await db.Parents.AddAsync(new Parent{});
// entry.Entity.Children.Add(new Child {}); // This works
entry.Entity.Children.Add(new Child { ChildId: 1 }); // This does not work
await db.SaveChangesAsync() // Getting concurrent exception here
...
```

I don't want to change the logic, such: saving parent first, create new context and save then child with its old ChildId. So do you guys have any good solution for this? Is this EF Core or Devart MySql feature?

Comment: Don;t call `SaveChanges` multiple times. Just don't. That method is meant to persist *all* pending changes. You don't need to call it multiple times, doing that *breaks EF* and its built-in Unit-Of-Work functionality

Comment: Can you explain how it is not working? Are you getting an error because there's a Child record already with a ChildId of 1?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I call it twice, because I'm doing first in real code the big remove range transaction and then recreate entities with some new and some old child entities. For some reason .NET Core 2 and EF6 was too slow to add or update, so I use faster way to do it. Not sure how about 3.1, but anyway  I found a solution for my problem and I answered it to below.

Comment: @soreal so now you have N+2 problems. The N+1 problems that caused the delay and the broken transaction semantics. Instead of covering up the original error, you should find out what's wrong with your code. EF is neither broken nor slow when used properly. On the other hand `big remove` suggests you're misusing it. ORMs are **not** meant for ETL. Instead of loading 100 records just to delete them, run a `DELETE WHERE ...`. If you want bulk insertions use MySqlBulkCopy. If you want bulk upsert, insert the data into a staging table then update or insert to the target.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error. You need ParentId key to add a child. And since you db is empty now try to use this:

```
[]Child children= { new Child {ParentId=1, ChildrenId=10}}
db.Parents.Add(new Parent { ParentId=1 , Chilren=  children};
```

Or if your dbcontext is configured right way you can try inverse:

```
db.Children.Add( new Child { ChidrentId=10, Parent= new Parent {ParentId=1}}
```

But if your Ids are auto-seeds and your dbcontext is configured the right way  it would be enough:

```
db.Parents.Add(new Parent { Children= { new Child {}} };
```

Only if you have a parent object already, you can use like this:

```
db.Children.Add( new Child {ParentId=...,ChildId=...})
```

Comment: I didn't have an error on the code. Code was fine, you can read the answer in below.

Answer (score 0):

Like the topic says that it was concurrent exception, so I debugged and found that for some reason EF core did set the entity state as 'Modified' if I was using old ChildId, even if the old entity didn't exists on the context anymore. So here's the very simply solution:

```
db.Entry(childEntity).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: That's because what you did is actually a bug. You already told EF that this ID is deleted, so it's tracked as deleted. `the old entity didn't exists on the context anymore` on the contrary, it does exist, as deleted. Why would any library *add* an already deleted PK? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work. It *does* track the entities it loads, so it knows which were updated, inserted or deleted.

Comment: Reusing the PKs of deleted entities would cause serious problems in any database, whether you use an ORM or not. Related rows now point to the wrong object. If any of that data was exported to another system, you'd end up with inconsistent data. PKs shouldn't be reused

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for clarification. I reuse the same Id, because the real data is basically read only results. For some cases the data is re created with different children and saved to database. When recreated the large data range, saving was the bottle neck, so I had to use drop and create method, instead add or update. The data is shown in client view and UI basically can show the difference when old ID can be used to target rows I will try add or update way with .Net core 3.1 or 5. The other way is to create unique index that is used instead of Id.

Comment: it sounds like a lot of fixes on top of fixes to cover problems with the actual database design. A primary key always is a unique index, which suggest that what you call `ID` isn't really an ID but something else.  A Data warehouse or reporting database are real read-only databases, and they aren't populated by ORMs, they're fed by ETL jobs. Primary keys are never reused. Even if there's a business key, it's stored separately, with an auto-generated ID/PK used to identify rows